# Fluent with Spring [j2ee applications] , more insight on MEAN & MERN stack

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mean-stack, mern

I recently took some time to learn SPRING framework and develop a simple application which follows the MVC pattern.
But, later I came across MEAN & MERN Stack development to develop delicious looking Single page applications.

What I cannot understand is why and where to start?

Like,

- should I move on with SPRING Boot and use ANGULAR or React for front-end alone,[I don't know if this is possible]

or

- should I completely ditch J2EE [java] and start MEAN & MERN Stack development [javascript].

Tried googling some stuff, but didn't quite answer my question Except for the fact that many developers prefer **MERN > MEAN > J2EE with SPRING**.

Some insight over what should I start or continue with and maybe with some resources[*Well, I found some CRUD Examples for both MEAN & MERN and would refer official docs for learning angular or react respectively, Would like to know if there is anything else I should know.*] to kickstart would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes .It is very common and possible that using spring-boot as a backend API to provide data to the front-end JS framework such as react , angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would shift away from Java to be honest. Oracle started charging money this year for using Java SE . I would imagine more new projects would move away from java for this reason and just use node.

java would be good if you plan on working for a large enterprise, but those companies usually dont use React for a frontend.

MERN is a popular stack for tutorials but in production apps I have seen a SQL based database systems, such as PSQL, to be more popular.

So I would learn React/Node/express with a SQL based database instead of MongoDB.